# clang 3.8+ -fopenmp on linux: ld cannot find -lomp

Tags: linux, clang, openmp

I have installed clang 3.8 from the base repositories for both Debian Jessie and Fedora 24.  When I try to compile a simple HelloWorld.cpp test program with clang++, and i pass the -fopenmp flag, in both cases i get the same error:

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lomp
clang-3.8: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I see that if I instead pass -fopenmp=libgomp, it works.  However, the Clang OpenMP website says that the OpenMP runtime is shipped with Clang 3.8.  Why, then, can it not find the default libomp library?  I do not see this library anywhere on my system.

Comment: Strange : Suse only has `/usr/lib(64)/libomp.so` (from the package `llvm-clang`) . ... But I found no `libomp.so` or `libomp.a` in any Fedora or Debian. .... Hints https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=811283 ... Ref. https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q="libomp.so"

Comment: Found this : "If you want to check out **libomp** (required for OpenMP support), run:" ... at **llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted** http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html ... But may be libomp is an older library ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33357029/using-openmp-with-clang >>> **libiomp**

Answer (score 11):

There is good chances that the OpenMP development package is missing on your system.
On Ubuntu: `sudo apt install libomp-dev`

Answer (score 1):

### **TL;DR**

If you have `libomp.so` for llvm in somewhere like `/usr/lib/llvm-12/lib` make file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/libomp.conf` with the line `/usr/lib/llvm-12/lib` in it, then run `sudo ldconfig`.

---

---

### Intro

In my case, I had libomp-12-dev installed, but it was not in my linker's library path. See the footnote on how I found the library. There are a couple solutions in this scenario:

---

### Add library path with `ldconfig`

If you want this in your default library path, consider using `ldconfig` *[[man page]](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ldconfig.8.html)*.

This will look for files in `/etc/ld.so.conf`. For me, running Ubuntu 20.04, this file only points to including files in the directory `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`.

```
$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
```

As such, I made a config `llvm-libomp-12` in my `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` directory that looks like this:

```
$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libomp.conf
# libomp.so for llvm
/usr/lib/llvm-12/lib
```

Then I asked ldconfig to update the paths with `sudo ldconfig`. You can add the `-v` flag and it will print all libraries and paths it is aware of.

---

### Add library to environment variable

We can also direct the linker to our library using the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable

This may be advantageous if you're on a multiuser system and don't want to impact others, or if you have temporary changes to your library paths you would like to make in your shell.

See what your current `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is with `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. You may not have this set by default. Add paths to this variable, each delimited by a colon.

For your current shell session, simply append or prepend to your `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` like this (assuming bash, zsh, or fish >v3.0):

```
export "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/lib"
```

Or for a more permanent change limited to your user, add the above export to your shell's config file (e.g. `~/.bashrc`).

---

### Manually specify library path(s) in compiler flags

Nice for a one-off specific library that you don't always want in your default library paths. Specify the path to the library as a flag like this:

`-L/path/to/lib`

For example:

`clang++ -L/usr/lib/llvm-12/lib [...]`

`make -L/usr/lib/llvm-12/lib`

---

### Footnotes

#### On searching

If you don't know where a given library you need is, you can use things like `find`. Personally though, I used a package called `mlocate` that indexes files on my machine and allows you to search them.

- Installing mlocate

  - `sudo apt install mlocate`
- Updating the indexes

  - `sudo updatedb`
- Searching for a substring

  - `locate libomp.so`

When I searched for where my libomp libraries were, I did this:

```
$ locate libomp.so
/usr/lib/llvm-12/lib/libomp.so
/usr/lib/llvm-12/lib/libomp.so.5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libomp.so.5
```

Notably it seemed like clang was using the libomp.so.5 in the linux-gnu directory, but I needed it to be using the llvm library.

#### Environment used in this post

```
$ lsb_release --all
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

$ uname -a
Linux bip 5.8.0-48-generic #54~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sat Mar 20 13:40:25 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

#### TODO

Some notes that could be added to this question:

- Confirm and list priority of env vars vs config files vs flags (does this vary between compilers and linkers?)
- Ordering library paths when using multiple config files (can we prefix with numbers to ensure the order libraries are parsed?)

Answer (score 0):

If you have libomp installed correctly you will need to use `-fopenmp=libomp`. `libgomp` is for gcc. You might check that clang isn't symbollically linked to gcc on your computer.