# Having trouble installing software with MACOS Catalina terminal (Python3.8)

Tags: gcc, installation, clang, macos-catalina, python-3.8

This it the part of the installation process that starts throwing an error:

```
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic \
 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=0 \
 -I/Users/kaurd2/env_majiq_2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include \
 -I/Users/kaurd2/env_majiq_2/include \
 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 \
 -c majiq/src/polyfitnb.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/majiq/src/polyfitnb.o \
 -fopenmp -O3
```

```
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: It could be that it requires a newer gcc, a quick search on "openmp gcc" seems to indicate that it was first added to version 4.2, you should be able to check your gcc version by typiing gcc --version

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it looks like I have the latest gcc version installed

Comment: Actually it looks like you have clang installed. Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33357029/using-openmp-with-clang